# How to perform Bluetooth LE Ping on Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I want to validate the physical layer between two BLE devices.
Both controllers run Linux with bluez, although with different feature sets.

Both controllers support the `LE Ping` feature

Bluetooth specification details this feature as follows:

- Master device sends a `LL_PING_REQ` PDU
- Slave device responds with the `LL_PING_RSP` PDU

I'm not sure how to perform this in practical terms.

Is there an included tool for sending and receiving these commands? If so, how can I use them?

Comment: L2CAP ping is a different feature which is only available for Bluetooth Classic, i.e. not BLE.

Comment: This can be done using the HCI command "Write Authenticated Payload Timeout command". I have no idea if BlueZ supports it though, or how it is activated.